# Android Studio 4.1 database inspector not showing Realm Database

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, database-inspector

I already update andorid studio to 4.1 stable version and I am trying to use Database inspector on my app, I am using Realm Database but it's not showing anything.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this docs [Debug your database with the Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database):

> In Android Studio 4.1 and higher, the Database Inspector allows you to
> inspect, query, and modify your app's databases while your app is
> running. This is especially useful for database debugging. **The
> Database Inspector works with plain SQLite and with libraries built on
> top of SQLite, such as Room.**

I dont think that it works with Realm

Comment: It won't work with Realm, because Realm does not use SQLite at it's core. The Database Inspector is designed around SQLite only.